# C fopen can't open absolute path OS X

Tags: objective-c, c, fopen

I'm trying to open a file using an absolute path. My app sends what file it wants opened using objective-c, and opens it using C. I try to open it using this

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSOpenPanel *o = [[NSOpenPanel alloc]init];
[o setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[o setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[o setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[o setPrompt:@"Open"];
if ([o runModal] == NSOKButton )
{
    // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
    // files and directories selected.
    NSArray* files = [o URLs];

    // Loop through all the files and process them.
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
    {
        NSString* fileName = [[files objectAtIndex:i] absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"%@", fileName);

        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", openFile([fileName UTF8String])];
        self.tv.string = str;
    }

}
```

the openfile method is this

```
char *openFile(const char file[1024]){
FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
static char c[1000];
char *d;
if (f!=NULL) {
    if (fgets(c, 1000, f) !=NULL){
        d = c;
    }
    else{
        d = "No text";
    }
}
else{
    d="error";
    perror(f);
}
fclose(f);

return d;
}
```

it sends an absolute path like `file://localhost/Users/macuser/test.txt`, but the `perror(f);`
returns `No such file or directory`. Why does this happen when I know the file exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file://localhost/Users/macuser/test.txt` is a URI, not a file path. Process the string to strip out everything up to and including `/localhost` and it should be fine.

Note that this sort of solution will only work if there are no escape sequences in the URI. As noted below, it may be simpler to send the path from the Objective C side.

Comment: URIs may contain % escapes too so naive conversion like this answer proposes is not a good general solution.

Comment: @R..: I gave a straightforward way to do what was asked in the question, but yes, for a general solution more processing would be needed, but as above it's easier to do this from the ObjC side.